# Change the marker thickness in matplotlib scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, marker

I have the following marker in my python matplotlib scatter plot:

[image]

made by the code:

```
plt.scatter(x,y,c=z,cmap=cm.bwr,marker='X',s=800,linewidth=1,edgecolor='k')
```

I want the X to be the same size, but I want the red part to be 'thinner'. More like a real 'X' I guess.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thicker the edge, the thinner the face. Alternatively a marker `"x"` can be used

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


for lw in [1,3,5,7]:
    plt.scatter([lw], [1], c="gold", s=1000, marker="X", 
                linewidth=lw, edgecolor='k')
    plt.scatter([lw], [0], c="gold", s=lw*300, marker="x")

plt.margins(.2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I've asked 3 questions tonight and you've answered all of them. Thank you! :)

Comment: Ok... so i spend today 1 hour because i was using a lower 'x' instead of 'X'...
Thank you a lot for your answer!